# Confusion over AWS EBS Snapshot

Tags: amazon-ebs

I'm confused with the incremental backup mechanism of EBS snapshot. Suppose If i start taking EBS volume backup say at 8 AM. During backing up if there is any activity/changes being performed on the volume, does it also gets backed up or it will backup only the changes till 8AM.
Thumb rule is that the volume should have less activity or no activity while taking backup. Any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 1):

in-progress snapshot is not affected by ongoing reads and writes to the volume.It will contain changes only till 8AM.
Refer http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-creating-snapshot.html